# Ubuntu Budgie dash goes off screen after upgrade 17.10 >> 18.04

Tags: upgrade, display, amd-graphics, 18.04, budgie

This is my problem:

[image]

The search area in the top left of the panel goes off the screen. The whole thing is just a whole lot bigger than it was before I upgraded. How can this be rectified?

Comment: What theme are you using. What is your screen vertical resolution?

Comment: @fossfreedom Arc-Dark. The result is the same regardless of theme. Resolution is 1366x768.

Comment: Is the system theme checkbox ticked? If you choose Pocillo Slim for the theme does that make a difference?

Comment: @fossfreedom Yes, though if it is unchecked it makes no difference. After trying Pocillo Slim, the result is still the same.

Comment: It does look like an issue with the number of categories you have combined with your low resolution screen. You probably need to hide various categories and combine icons of relate categories. Use menulibre for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use menulibre to remove menu items to free up space on screen.
Credit goes to @fossfreedom.